# Font weight in multiple browsers

Tags: html, css, image, web, stylesheet

I am using font-weight on my website present [here](http://smalltheme.esy.es/image-bg/index.html) .

Now it works fine on google chrome but appears very thin on safari. Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Have you checked **Related** questions to the right? Possible duplicate of  <pick one>

Comment: “Here” is not a problem description. Include relevant code in the question itself, and preferably provide a jsfiddle too.

Comment: I provided the link. And thanks to Josh he solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with font-rendering across browsers. One thing that helps in Chrome is to use `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`.

Comment: But the problem is with safari

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that it probably looks 'thicker' in Chrome because it's rendering incorrectly. By adding the antialiasing to Chrome you see a truer rendering of the font, as you see in Safari. If it's too thin in both you may need to up the font-weight.

Comment: Thanks let me try it out

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. Still getting the same layout. Could you please check the link i attached. Your help would mean a lot.  Thank you

Comment: One thing that seems to help is removing the vegas overlay background texture.

Comment: Could you please specify the file. Incide the css or the javascript?

Comment: Sure. This one here http://smalltheme.esy.es/image-bg/img/overlays/02.png. The small texture is kind of fighting the thin font. If that still doesn't help I'd suggest choosing a new, thicker font, or upping the font-weight.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Josh Rutherford. I would let you know if it works

Comment: No problem, hope it helps

Comment: Sure try Helvetica Neue. It's fairly similar and seems to hold up better on my end.